# How to deploy a Vagrant VM as an Openstack image? (Vagrant 1.4.3, provider is Virtualbox.)

Tags: cloud, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualization, openstack

I am currently trying to deploy a Vagrant VM (with Virtualbox as provider) into Openstack.

The way my Vagrant is set up apart from the Vagrant environment folder where the Vagrantfile and .vagrant directory live there is a 'Virtualbox VMs' folder in my home directory, with a folder for each instantiated VM, and inside each one a .vbox (from what I gather, basically an XML file) and a .vmdk file.

The vmdk is the file I am most interested in as it seems to be the virtual hard drive where the VM is stored. I have tried uploading this as an Openstack image (supported image formats are raw, vhd, **vmdk**, vdi, iso, qcow2, aki, ari, ami. ) but when creating an instance with it it fails with the error:

> 'No valid host was found. Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for
>   instance b7bceab4-8ba5-4c8a-ba83-72ba63d66cc7'

After googling it this error seemed to indicate a resources problem, but I think this is misleading as I am able to create other Images / Instances after this fine, indicating to me there is something wrong with how I am using the vmdk from Vagrant to set up an Image.

There doesn't seem to be very much information online for running Vagrant VMs on Openstack so any information pointing me in the right direction would be very much appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this! At least for small (2GB) VM images!

What I did was create an image using the vmdk from 'Virtualbox VMs / ' and when I instantiated it I made sure to select the 'xl' size. The VM then started as normal and I was able to access it in the 'console' view. It seems it was a resources issue after all! This worked for a ~2GB CentOS64 image. I used a 20GB minimum for hard drive and 1024MB minimum for RAM.

It seems that the vmdk's from Virtualbox style Vagrant boxes do indeed work on Openstack, which is something I wasn't sure of.